# Javascript / jQuery Populating Multidimensional Arrays... Array with array elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to populate a multidimensional array (array with array elements) via Javascript or jQuery... `push()` is probably the wrong method to use, but I've tried a couple of others and I can't seem to get beyond single dimensional arrays. Here's the latest try so far - any advice or snippets on how I might be able to populate arrays per element of an existing global array appreciated!

```
<script>
var fred=[];
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    fred.push(['a',i]);
    $("#disp").html(i);
}
alert(fred.toSource());
$("#disp").html(fred.toSource());​
</script>

<div id="disp">abc</div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eJbm7/

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you're after?  It's very abstract and hard to understand what the goal is at the moment...if you gave an example of what you *expect* the result to be it could be very helpful.

Comment: i'd like to be able to assign multiple elements to each index of a main array - similar to what i'd do in php, but in javascript... this way, i can later loop through each "row" to display each array's "columns"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.push` should work fine. After all, a two-dimensional array is just an array of arrays.

The link you provided does pop up a message with a two-dimensional array. What's the problem?

Comment: `fred` is an array of arrays: `[['a', 0], ['a', 1], ['a', 2]]`. Maybe you're trying to use the number as a position? Then construct a separate "row" array, fill it up using `row.push('abc')` and then `fred.push(row)` for each row.

Comment: ahh! sorry my original error had to do with jQuery.inArray not being able to process multidimensional arrays... i had thought it was because my array was not populating.